# Prove that an alternating series converges to a value between the first term and the sum of the first two terms

Tags: analysis

This is used in an elementary proof that $e$ is irrational.  I can prove this, but what I am doing is not particular nice looking.  In the proof, the author says this is obvious but I can't seem to write it out so simply.

\begin{equation}
S = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty (-1)^k a_k
\end{equation}

where $a_k > a_{k + 1} > 0$ and $a_k \rightarrow 0$.  So, I want to show that

\begin{equation}
a_0 - a_1 < S < a_0
\end{equation}

Comment: The series doesn't have to converge with just these conditions, for example take $a_k = 1 + \frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: right, I will add that $a_k \rightarrow 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

For a convergent series *with decreasing terms* (which is almost certainly what the author's talking about, because the claim isn't true in general!) observe that every odd partial sum like $a_0 - a_1 + a_2 - a_3 + a_4$ can be written as 
$a_0$ minus a collection of nonnegative numbers, like $a_0 - (a_1 - a_2) - (a_3 - a_4)$, hence is no greater than $a_0$. Do the same thing for even partial sums compared to $a_0 - a_1$, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

The even partial sums are positive and decreasing, so they converge. The odd partial sums are bounded from above by $a_0$ and increasing, so they also converge. The even and odd partial sums must converge to the same limit because their difference $S_{2n} - S_{2n+1} = a_{2n+1}$ converges to zero. Hence the entire series converges, and now John Hughes' argument proves the bounds on the limit.